# How to show data from two ViewModels in one View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to fill 2 divs in View with data from 2 ViewModels, but I have a problem.

My 2 viewModels:

```
public class ChatLogsNameTimeViewModel
{
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChatLogs> ChatLogs { get; set; }
}
```

Which means I want to show data from ChatLogsNameTimeViewModel in one div in View and data from UserProfile in other div in View.

This is my ViewModel that uses both viewModels above:

```
public class ChatLogsUsersViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ChatLogsNameTimeViewModel> ChatLogs { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my Index() action in controller:

```
var chatLogs = db.getChatLog().ToList();
var users = dba.getOnlineUsers().ToList();

var view = new ChatLogsUsersViewModel(chatLogs, users);
return View(view);
```

My problem is that I can not access to ViewModel attributes at all.

When I create foreach loop in view all I can access is this:

[image]
Which means I cannot access attributes at all to print them in foreach.

I have this in View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Chat.Models.ChatLogsUsersViewModel>
```

I assume that I am not doing something right in my controller. I have methods `getChatLog()` and `getOnlineUsers()` implemented in Model, they work alone no problem. I just don't know how to make them work together in one view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the type of you view.

You are not passing the view a list of `Chat.Models.ChatLogsUsersViewModel`, you only have one and this model has two lists.

So update it to:

```
@model Chat.Models.ChatLogsUsersViewModel
```

Comment: You should be able to access the list using Model._chatLogs and Model._users

Answer (score 2):

Your model is strongly typed towards the wrong model. As Queti put it, your model should be typed `@model Chat.Models.ChatLogsUsersViewModel`.

As is, your model is attempting to access a collection of these models. You should find that if you do:

```
@for each (var x in Model) {
    x.
}
```

x is then a single `ChatLogsUsersViewModel` and should display its properties in your dev environment. But again, this is not how you want to strongly type your model here.

If I'm not mistaken, this is what you are trying to do, and you can still access your data using a for each loop:

```
@model Chat.Models.ChatLogsUsersViewModel

for each (var log in Model._chatLogs) {
    @<div>@log.Message</div>
}
...
for each (var user in Model._users) {
    @<div>@user.UserName</div>
}
```

Comment: I can not use foreach loop if I don't use IEnumerable as view type. What do you mean by "this is not how you want to strongly type your model here."? Can you elaborate please ;)

Comment: You can use a foreach loop on any IEnumerable collection. The ViewModel does not have to be IEnumerable. In your case, you can do a foreach loop through each of the two collections on the view model we are suggesting.

Comment: I revised my answer using a for each loop, is this what you are attempting to do?

Comment: you are correct guys. thank you. i gave an answer to queti since he was first, thanks for your revisions, very good guy.